# Using string array as criteria in VBA autofilter

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, autofilter

I've searched other posts and found similar issues but nothing that could help me specifically. I'm trying to take an array of strings and use it as a filter criteria. It's tricky because the array is created by a function and has a variable number of elements and contents. I need the autofilter to take it and check **column E** for each one of its elements.

I've tried it two ways

1)

```
With Sheet17

    .Range("E1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(arr)

End With
```

Result: Applies a filter to column E but fails to select any of the options

2)

```
For i = 0 To counter - 1

    With Sheet17

        .Range("E1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(arr(i))

    End With

Next
```

**Note:** Counter is an integer representing the number of elements in the array.

**Result:** This one correctly loops through the array but only selects the last option on the filter - presumably because every time it loops back through it starts over and unchecks every other option so by the end only the most recent option remains checked.

Answer (score 17):

You do not need to transpose a single element from an array and you cannot put criteria into the 5<sup>th</sup> field if you are only referencing column E.

```
Dim i As Long, arr As Variant
arr = Array(1, 3)

With Sheet17
    'to filter each value in the array one at a time
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        .Columns("E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr(i)
    Next i

    'my values were numbers - AutoFilter likes strings in its array
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = CStr(arr(i))
    Next i

    'to filter all values in the array at once specify xlFilterValues
    .Columns("E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, _
                             Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
```

Specify the `Operator:=xlFilterValues` when passing an array and the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) likes strings as the values in an array.

Answer (score 14):

The Excel documentation for [AutoFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) provides some guidance. The `Operator` parameter takes a [XlAutoFilterOperator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839625.aspx) that specifies how `Criteria1` is interpreted. In your case, specifying a value of `xlFilterValues` will cause `Criteria1` to be properly interpreted as an array of filter values.

The following example demonstrates this:

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Array("Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie")

Sheet17.Range("E1").AutoFilter _
    Field:=5, _
    Criteria1:=arr, _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```