# Excel VBA autofilter crit

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up a filter in excel where the resulting data should include both criteria which are contradicting.

Example:

```
Set 1
    Field =2 ,Criteria1 =x  field = 3 criteria= 1

Set 2
    Field =2 ,Criteria1 <>x  field = 3 criteria= 2
```

Where the end result is all rows which satisfy either set of conditions

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the point?  That would include everything.

Comment: You would use an array for having multiple conditions; though I agree with Rdster that this would give all results.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404176/using-string-array-as-criteria-in-vba-autofilter

Comment: Field 3 has many different values, I want it to show me rows where field 2 is x and field 3 is 1 and rows where field 2 is not x and field 3 is 2. Maybe I didn't explain properly